# Is it possible to switch off the trackpad in OS X with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, trackpad

I'm using OS X almost entirely using the keyboard, and it helps to have the trackpad disabled most of the time. But I'd also like to be able to enable it every so often for individual tasks - is it possible to switch it off and on with a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

No way right now as far as I'm aware. I'd like to see an option to disable the trackpad while typing, for a user-selected number of ms after a keystroke.  That would solve the most irritating thing about the macbook for me.