# Is it possible to change the "Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse is present" setting with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: terminal, automator, mouse, trackpad

I like to use my MacBook with a USB mouse most of the time, and keep "Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present" option checked to avoid accidentally moving the cursor while typing. However, occasionally it's useful to switch it back on for certain tasks, and I'd like to be able to do this with a keyboard shortcut.

I've tried recording the process of switching it on/off with Automator, but when I copy the resulting script and run it, it gets as far as the Accessibility settings and then gives me a syntax error saying 'Can not click checkbox 3 of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences"'.

I've also tried setting "USBMouseStopsTrackpad" in defaults to 0 and 1 in the terminal, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I can see this changing to 0 or 1 when I check/uncheck the box, so I'm fairly certain I've got the right option, but nothing happens when I change it.

Apologies if this is really obvious and I'm just not seeing it! I'm still not too familiar with this machine. I'm aware of this question:

[Is it possible to switch off the trackpad in OS X with a keyboard shortcut](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135707/is-it-possible-to-switch-off-the-trackpad-in-os-x-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)

but I don't think it's a duplicate as I'm trying to do something slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done *natively* with no third-party anything needed, simply and easily using **AppleScript** and **UI Scripting**.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* can be implemented in a number of different ways, as a *script*, an **AppleScript** *application*, or as an **Automator** *service* , the latter of which can have a *keyboard shortcut* assigned to it.

Specifically how to implement as an **Automator** *service* has been covered more then enough times that a **Google** search should provide an answer on how to do that. I know I written directions for it more times than I can remember.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me and toggles the "**Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present:**" *check box*:

```
if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
end if
repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Mouse" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        click checkbox 1 of group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

- Note that the *value* of the `delay` *commands* may need to be adjusted for your system, and or additional `delay` *commands* may or may not be needed. Adjust *values* of and or add/remove the `delay` *commands* as appropriate.
- This was tested and works under **macOS High Sierra**; however, note that depending on the version of **OS X/macOS** you're running, the `click checkbox ...` line of *code* may need to be adjusted depending on the version of the **OS**.

For example, with **macOS Catalina** you'd need to use:

```
click checkbox 2 of tab group 1 of group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
```

---

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Why does your script first quit System Preferences?

Comment: @JakeRobb, It first quits **System Preferences** because it's using **UI Scripting** and if **System Preferences** is already open and at a **modal sheet**, which there are some, then without it the _script_ would fail. That said, granted the chances of that happening are slim, however, it's always better to write _code_ that can handle the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Macroing this is a bit janky, but it's totally doable.

I'd recommend using [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) for this. It's sort of like Automator.... Not free, but it does have a trial and it's definitely worth it. You could do this same thing in Automator or Applescript too, but it's way simpler in KBM.

**KBM has some great Actions when it comes to navigating gui:**

- [**Pause Until**](https://wiki.keyboardmaestro.com/action/Pause_Until)

  - The Pause Until action pauses until criteria for conditions are met.
- [**Press a Button**](https://wiki.keyboardmaestro.com/action/Press_a_Button)

  - The Press a Button action presses a named button in the front window.
- [**Select or Show a Menu Item**](https://wiki.keyboardmaestro.com/action/Select_or_Show_a_Menu_Item)

  - The Select or Show a Menu Item action selects a menu item OR shows (opens) a menu in the main menubar.
- [**Insert Text by Typing**](https://wiki.keyboardmaestro.com/action/Insert_Text_by_Typing)

  - The Insert Text by Typing action converts plain (simple) text into keystrokes and then types each of them individually. It only works with characters that can be typed on the keyboard with one or two keystrokes (eg Option-e e usually types é, and Keyboard Maestro can duplicate that typing).
- [**Type a Keystroke**](https://wiki.keyboardmaestro.com/action/Type_a_Keystroke)

  - The Type Keystroke action lets you type a single keystroke, pretty much any kind of keystroke you can type on the keyboard.
- [**Move or Click Mouse**](https://wiki.keyboardmaestro.com/action/Move_or_Click_Mouse)

  - The Move or Click Mouse action allows you to move, click or move and click the mouse using any mouse button, and optionally dragging.
  - This is a relatively small thing, but I think it's great that it can restore the mouse location after the action is completed. That option is a bit hidden though.

#### The steps to produce the action along with light explanations:

[Picture of the macro steps (Link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWRh4.png)

Not the fastest macro ever (~3seconds), but sure beats diving into the menus manually.

**As you are making this macro, make sure to run the unfinished macro after every step to make sure everything is exactly as they should be.**

1. Action name: `Activate a Specific Application`

   - Activate: `System Preferences`
   - > Opens up System Preferences
2. Action name: `Pause Until`

   - New Condition: `Menu Condition`
   - A menu item: with this name `Accessibility` is enabled
   - > This more or less makes sure the window is active and Accessibility is a menu item you can navigate to.
3. Action name: `Move a Window`

   - Move to: →`0` ↓ `0`
   - > This makes sure that the preferences window is in your main screen. It's only important because if at any point you manually drag the window to your secondary screen, all the actions that rely on coordinates would fail without this and the next 'Move a Window action'.
4. Action name: `Select or Show a Menu Item`

   - Select menu in: `System Preferences`
   - Menu Title: `View`
   - Menu Item `Accessibility`
   - > You can also just click `Menu ▾` on the top left of this action to choose the menu item from there, as long as System Preferences is open. That makes it super easy to simulate clicking any menu item.
5. Action Name: `Pause`

   - Pause for : `1` seconds.
   - > This is a bit of a mystery. I wanted to use pause until window title is 'Accessibility', which works if you go to the Accessibility page in System Preferences and check the action. KBM says the value is true when you're there. However, it kept failing when I actually ran the macro. I also tried the 'Pause Until Pixel Condition’ and that failed as well I guess the condition became true before any interaction was possible… The point of using the 'Pause Until' action is to make sure that whatever we want to do next actually triggers at the right moment. When you use a static pause or no pause at all, there is a chance that it occasionally takes longer than usual and the simulated keypress just goes into the ether and the macro gets stuck or worst case scenario: it actually does something totally different, like sends a missile warning alert to all Hawaiians or something. The few spots where I used a static pause should be fine since they are all in the same page of the same window so there *shouldn't* be any weird issues brought on by those, but if it doesn't do what it's supposed to do: increase the static delay. You may also want to add 'Pause' between some of the other actions that are not separated by a delay, if it doesn't seem to work. Slower machines typically require bigger delay.
6. Action Name: `Type a Keystroke`

   - Simulate keystroke: `Cmd+F`
   - Click the Simulate keystroke input and press the shortcut keys.
   - > If this window is already active, this sort of defaults the position to the search so the next keystroke goes to the right place
7. Action name: `Move a Window`

   - Change `Move to` to `Center`
   - > This makes sure all the actions using coordinates hit the right spots.
8. Action Name: `Type a Keystroke`

   - Simulate keystroke: `Tab`
   - You can select it from the dropdown list or type it in.
   - > Activates the list on the left side of `System Preferences > Accessibility` window.
9. Action Name: `Pause Until`

   - New Condition: `Pixel Condition`
   - Click the <kbd>Get</kbd>

     - It'll give you 5 seconds to position your mouse on top of the color.
     - Make the window active and hover your mouse anywhere on top of the blue edge to get that color
     - [image]
   - > This just makes sure the next action is triggered at the right time.
10. Action Name: `Type a Keystroke`

    - Simulate keystroke: `End`
    - You can select it from the dropdown list or type it in.
    - > Activates the list on the left side of `System Preferences > Accessibility` window.
11. Action Name: `Type a Keystroke`

    - Simulate keystroke: `Alt+Down Arrow`
    - Click the Simulate keystroke input and press the shortcut keys.
    - This menu on the left can retain the last visited item next time you open it, so we do this just to make sure the first item is selected or else the next pause until could fail occasionally.
12. Action Name: `Pause Until`

    - New Condition: `Pixel Condition`
    - Again the same thing as with the last Pause Until → Pixel Condition. Press the <kbd>Get</kbd> button, activate the Accessibility window and pick a color from the active item's background.
    - [image]
    - > This just makes sure the next action is triggered at the right time.
13. Action: `Move or Click Mouse`

    - Relative to the `Absolute position`
    - Click the gear menu on the top right corner of the action and select `Restore Mouse Location`.
    - Press the <kbd>Get</kbd> button and hover over the “Mouse & Trackpad”
    - > I chose to use relative to the absolute position since the Pixel Conditions can't be relative to the current window... Doesn't really matter much.
    - [image]
14. Action Name: `Pause Until`

    - New Condition: `Pixel Condition`
    - Again the same thing as with the last Pause Until → Pixel Condition. Press the <kbd>Get</kbd> button, activate the Accessibility window and pick a color from the active item's background.
    - [image]
    - > This just makes sure the next action is triggered at the right time.
15. Action: `Move or Click Mouse`

    - Relative to the `Absolute position`
    - Click the gear menu on the top right corner of the action and select `Restore Mouse Location`.
    - Press the <kbd>Get</kbd> button and hover over the `Ignore built-in tackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present`
    - > I chose to use relative to the absolute position since the Pixel Conditions can't be relative to the current window... Doesn't really matter much.
    - [image]
16. Action Name: `Pause`

    - Pause for `.6` seconds
    - > You may want to lengthen this if you feel like you can't quite see the value changing and you'd like to... This delay was added for that reason, but it does go by pretty fast. Try something like 1 second...
17. Action Name: `Quit a Specific Application`

    - Quit: `System Preferences`.
    - You may want to disable this action for testing purposes.

Comment: You said, "I'm pretty sure the command line solutions are blocked by SIP.", well SIP has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with why using `defaults` to modify a _key's value_ in a `.plist` file fails to achieve the goal. The `defaults` _command_ was rendered almost useless as of OS X 10.8 and later where major changes were made that broke the effective use of it as compared to older versions of OS X. It still can be used in some cases but not nearly as many as it used to be where it once use to take immediate effect without necessarily having to kill a process to get the change to take.

Comment: @user3439894, I'm guessing it doesn't work in this situation since you didn't post that as an answer?

Comment: I didn't even try to use `defaults` in this use case. The point I was trying to make is, your statement I quoted in my previous comment is erroneous! SIP does not block the `defaults` _command_ from taking action on  `.plist` files in `~/Library/Preferences`. You should read: [About System Integrity Protection on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)

Comment: @user3439894, it's not that I didn't get what you said. You implied the command line option might still be on the table but didn't confirm if it actually was... I was focusing on finding a good answer to the question and you were focusing on telling me I was wrong in one of my statements.

Comment: You said, "You implied the command line option might still be on the table but didn't confirm if it actually was...", I never implied anything, only made statements of fact. There was nothing to confirm as it's specific use was not explicitly relevant to the comment I made! With no disrespect intended, it appears your assumption that SIP is in play here shows you do not have a good handle on SIP or `defaults`. I too was focused on providing a good answer, which I believe I did by showing it can be done natively with no third-party anything needed, simply and easily using AS and UI Scripting.

Comment: @user3439894, I get it. You are right and I am wrong. No need for further comments, dude...

Comment: @Joonas Even if you were mistaken about the SIP, this is still a good answer and I appreciate the effort - thank you!

Comment: @DrRelling, well I was only guessing that SIP was the reason why the terminal solutions didn't work and other than me mentioning this possibility, it had nothing to do with the meat of my answer, which is to forget about inputting stuff to Terminal or using Applescript because KBM makes it way easier. I did say "I'm pretty sure", but given the response by "user3439894", I probably should've worded it differently, like: "SIP could be the reason..." or not mention it at all, but I didn't think it was a big deal, because it definitely wasn't the main point of my answer, just a passing thought.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on @user3439894's answer due to insufficient reputation, but the correct line for **OS X Catalina** is:

```
click checkbox 2 of tab group 1 of group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
```

Note the "... of tab group 1 ..." bit, which is now necessary.

Comment: Why not edit the post in question. Comments are for things you’re not clear on, sounds like you can make that edit / addition using the edit command.